# Save GParted information to file

Tags: gparted

I need to save some information about the current partitioning of my hard drive.

I already did

```
fdisk -l > file.txt
```

GParted tells a bit more information (label, size, used). Is it possible to make GParted save this information to a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command-line tool of gparted is parted. For example you can list all devices with:

```
user@pc:~$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA ST980811AS (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 80,0GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  3072MB  3071MB  primary  linux-swap(v1)
 2      3072MB  23,1GB  20,0GB  primary  ext4            boot
 3      23,1GB  80,0GB  57,0GB  primary  ext4
```

For pipe it to a file use

```
sudo parted -l > file.txt
```

Please use the man page

```
man parted
```

for more details.